# Not possible to run subset of targets in parallel with Gnu Make 4.3 (MinGW-w64 port)

Tags: makefile, concurrency, parallel-processing, gnu-make, mingw-w64

Consider the following makefile:

```
.DEFAULT_GOAL := all

.PHONY: all
all: target0 target1 target2

# This line makes all targets run serially
#.NOTPARALLEL: target0

.PHONY: target0
target0:
    @python delayed_print.py 0

.PHONY: target1
target1:
    @python delayed_print.py 1
    
.PHONY: target2
target2:
    @python delayed_print.py 2
```

delayed_print.py is just a small Python script that prints the argument after some seconds so I can easily see what runs in parallel.

By default (with -j option for mingw32-make), Make runs all the targets in parallel. If I enable the .NOTPARALLEL line, then all targets run serially. Is this a bug? Am I doing something wrong?

My intention is to run a subset of the targets in parallel and force sequential execution of some targets.

For reference:

```
mingw32-make --version
GNU Make 4.3
Built for Windows32
Copyright (C) 1988-2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ability to give specific targets to `.NOTPARALLEL` was added in GNU Make 4.4, along with the `.WAIT` special target.

See the NEWS file: https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/NEWS?h=4.4.1#n137

Comment: Thank you @MadScientist. I should say that the original example does not do what I expected but that was the result from a misunderstand of .NOTPARALLEL semantics. With Make 4.4 and some refactoring of the script, it now works.